# Convolution derivative. Difference between $f '(0)$ and $(f(0))'$?

Tags: calculus

In deriving the second derivative of a convolution I end up with:

$\ (y*f)''(t) = (y''*f)(t) + y'(0)f(t) + (y(0))'f(t) + y(0)f'(t)$

Is$\ y(0)'$ different from$\ y'(0)$?

I was thinking since$\ y(0)$ is just a number that's it's derivative is zero and I can get rid of the$\ (y(0))'f(t)$ term in my answer.

Or did I just mess up somewhere else? My work is attached if it's a problem in that.

[convolution derivative work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD9p9.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange! Please use MathJax for formatting mathematical expressions. https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: How did you derive that?

Comment: I've attached my work now if that helps.

Comment: Normally the definition of a convolution is
$$(g*f)(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(t-v) \, f(v) \, dv.$$
Are you using functions that vanish for negative values since you have integral limits $0$ and $t$?

Comment: I believe so, I guess it's for functions only "supported" from $\ [0,\infty)$ and this is what my textbook said to use and I can't tell why.

Comment: Did $(y(0))'$ come about from you doing the product rule?

Comment: Yes, so I didn't realize that I can treat $\ f(0) $ as a constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is significant. $\ y(0) $ is a number so it's derivative is 0, thus the term goes away.